# Is there a way to change UI design of "MediaPlayer" component in android?

Tags: android, user-interface, media-player

Is there a way to change UI design of "MediaPlayer" component in android? I'm talking about the playButton, seekbar and all components it contains.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to modify it just change the drawables in the drawables folder of the App(I assume you have to look in the systems folder where all the stock apps are)